# Contrapositive and converse

Tags: real-analysis

The question is "If m + n is odd then m is odd or n is even".
How do I deal with the "or"?

PS. If the question was "If m + N is odd then m and n are odd", I would know that the contrapositive is "If m and n are even, then m + n is even" and converse is "if m and n are odd then m+n is odd.

Comment: Your post script isn't correct. The negation of "m and n are odd" (which is really "m is odd *and* n is odd") is "m is even *or* n is even".

Comment: Note that the contrapositive in the example you give, is not what you write. What is the opposite of "$m$ and $n$ are odd"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negation of "X or Y" is "not X *and* not Y".

Comment: The contrapositive becomes "If m is even and n is odd, then m+n is even", which I can prove wrong by {m=2k, n=2g+1, m+n=2(k+g)+1 which is odd}

Comment: Yes. That is correct.